# Thinking Sphinx, complex sorting - how can I combine extended sort with expr sort?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I want to sort by expression, then by some attribute ascending, then by another attribute ascending. Something like this: `:order => "(a < some constant) desc, b asc, c asc"`. How to get it?

Extended sorting refuses to work because of `<`. Expr fails because of commas.

I have managed to produce sorting equivalent to `:order => "(a < some constant) desc, b desc"` with `:order => "(a < some constant)", :sort_mode => :expr, :sort_by => :b`, but I can't add another attribute (`c`) to that sorting nor change sorting mode for `b` to asc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SetSelect](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#api-func-setselect) function allows for creating arbitrary sorts. I am not sure if it is available in thinking-sphinx, so modification of this gem may be necessary.